# Spring Boot Data JPA dropping commits with Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

Recently, my application has been seeing commits dropped and I am totally puzzled. No logs, no errors, everything continues as if things would be successful - but the commit is dropped. A dumbed down class where such an issue is occurring:

```
@Autowired MyRepository repo;

public Model saveMyModel(){
    final Model model = new Model();
    model.setFoo("something");
    repo.save(model) 

    model.setBar("bar")
    repo.save(model)

    return model; 
}
```

Most of our commits are making it through no problem to the DB, every once in (1 in 1000 maybe) a while we are seeing commits being dropped where `bar` was not being saved.

It does not matter if we mark this as `Transactional` on this behavior. I don't see any error logs from our DB, and this method never throws any errors, and downstream from the returned model from the method I can access  `bar` without issue. Just latter calls result in `Bar` as `null`.

We are Spring Boot 2.0 with Postgres 9.5, this is relatively new behavior in over 3 years of the application's history and I am unable to replicate outside of our prod environment.

Any thoughts? I would rather not have to flush everything to the DB immediately.

Comment: not sure what's you intend is, but you should be using `merge` once the bean is saved to update. Check section 3.3 https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate

Comment: Spring data should be handling the merge if the entity already exists though, they don't have an explicit merge method.

Comment: Well, internally it does the same. https://pastebin.com/fANAv9LH it's probably something else.

Comment: You can open an issue in spring boot JPA and link it StackOverflow. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa